# XGBoost forecast difference across different operating systems

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have XGBoost regression model in Python trained with same hyperparameters. It used same train, test, and prediction datasets. When the forecasts are compared between Ubuntu and Windows operating system, the forecasts came out to be quite significantly different (+20%).

Looking at the library it downloads from PyPi, the followings were observed:

Collecting xgboost==1.0.0
Downloading xgboost-1.0.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (24.6 MB)

Where as on Ubuntu environment, this was the wheel that was downloaded:
Downloading xgboost-1.0.0-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (109.7 MB)

I also tested using different versions of the XGBoost library and it didn't have any impacts.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Why is the root cause of this happening? What are the things can I do to make them consistent across different operating systems?

Comment: have you checked if the hyperparameters are the same?
It might be that there are differences in the default hyperparameters